# Jena Model Validation OntModel

Tags: owl, jena, linked-data

I have created an Ontology which i want use for validating instances, following is the test setup i have, couldnt get validation report one of uid is zero. which is **xsd:minExclusive "0"^^xsd:unsignedLong**.

Can anyone help m eunderstand best practice to use Jena, i am inteding to sue default model to recieve an input validating aginast ontModel and the merging in TDB backed model.

```
:Book rdf:type owl:Class ;
      rdfs:subClassOf Model .
```

and data Property

```
:uid rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ,
              owl:FunctionalProperty ;
     rdfs:domain :Model ;
     rdfs:range [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                  owl:onDatatype xsd:unsignedLong ;
                  owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:minExclusive "0"^^xsd:unsignedLong
                                         ]
                                       )
                ] .
```

Trying to use this ontology to validate data

```
    OntModel ontModel =  ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
    ontModel.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("model.owl").toExternalForm(), NS);
    // ontModel.write(System.out);
    Reasoner reasoner = ontModel.getReasoner().bindSchema(ontModel);
    Model data = createTestData();
    //data.write(System.out);
    InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, data);
    ValidityReport report = infModel.validate();
    if (report.isValid())
        System.out.println("valid");
```

and in the following code **//(index - 1) ensure at least one id of 0**

```
    public static Model createTestData() {
    Model instances = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    instances.setNsPrefix("rdfs", RDFS.getURI());
    instances.setNsPrefix("rdf", RDF.getURI());
    instances.setNsPrefix("a", NS);
    instances.setNsPrefix("", NS + "#");

    Property UID_PROPERTY = ResourceFactory.createProperty(NS + "#uid");

    IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(index -> {
        Resource r = instances.createResource(NS + "/item/" + (index - 1));
        
        r.addProperty(UID_PROPERTY, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral((index - 1)));
    });
    return instances;
}
```

Comment: `OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF` - that is an RDFS inference reasoner on an OWL DL ontology. Your OWL facet restriction is clearly out of RDFS inference scope

Comment: that said, constraint validation nowadays happens via SHACL constraint language - something Jena also does support